# How to know if CommandContext.getOptionValue returns default value or argument value?

Tags: spring-shell

Say I have command options Lorem and Ipsum.

Lorem is of type String[].class while Ipsum is of type boolean.class.

Lorem has a default value of "a,b,c" while Ipsum has a default value of "false".

My command can be "cmd --ipsum --lorem a,c,d".

Using `CommandContext.getCommandRegistration().get Options()` I can get the list of all the commands and their default values. Their default values are `String`, but the result value is not necessarily `String`, so I can't compare directly like so.

I know the conversation is happening using [convertOptionType()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/blob/main/spring-shell-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/shell/command/parser/Parser.java#L402) but I'm not sure how to use it properly, because arity is involved in there.